# how to put multiple buttons in scroll view?

Tags: iphone

how i can  put multiple buttons in scroll view with according to my requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,  something like this would work:

```
UIButton *button1 = ...  // (allocate this and initialize it)  
UIButton *button2 = ...  // (allocate this and initialize it)  

UIScrollView *scrollView = ...  // (allocate this and initialize it)  

[scrollView addSubview:button1];
[scrollView addSubview:button2];
```

This is basically how you add 2 buttons to a `UIScrollView`.

Now, if you want to do more, like put them so that only one is visible at a time or something, then position the frame of each button inside the `scrollView.contentSize` bounds.